# A question from my high school Olympiad.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> A set contains four numbers. The six pairwise sums of distinct elements of the set, in no particular order, are $189, 320, 287, 264, x, y$. Find the greatest possible value of: $x + y$.

By assuming the elements to be $a, b, c, d$ and by making $6$ different equations, I solved for $x+y$. The result came to be $793$. I am not sure if this is correct or not. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: @lioness99a so it's correct right?

Comment: Without working through the equations myself I can't be 100% sure but the method sounds alright

Comment: Are you sure it is 793, I get 761 as the maximum.

Comment: Agree with Satish, I'm getting 761 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the hint from @Dubs, you want d to be the largest, b and c the next larger than a.  For this to happen, you get ($d+a = 320, b+c = 287, b+a = 264 and c+a = 189$).

From the last two weg get $b-c = 75$ and from this and the second one  we get $2b = 362$, giving you $b = 181, a =83, c = 106$ and $d= 237$ and hence $x+y = 761$

Comment: I believe that $a+d$ or $b+c$ can be interchanged as the 3rd/4th smallest values. But regardless, they will arrive to 761.

Comment: Ah. Yes. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are off to a good start. But you want a stronger assumption. Otherwise, you will have a lot of cases to consider. For example, if $a+b=189$ should $a+c = 264$ or $c+d = 264$?

Try to assume that $a \le b \le c \le d$ instead.

This will still run into some choices. But those choices won't matter if you focus on solving for maximum value of $x + y$ so don't actually need to calculate $a,b,c,d$ individually.

Additional hint:

> Can you see why to get the maximum value of $x + y$ then $x + y = b + c + 2d$?